# Combined use of Functions Match & Min & Abs

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of electronic components, their names are in **Column A**, and their values are in **Column B**.

I want to search for each component (each row) the best match from all other rows (I don't want to use 2 `For` loops).I also need it in VBA, as I have other functions handling in VBA.

**Explanation** : the best match would be the row, where the component value , together with the searched component row, would be the closest to 36.

Example (see a section of my table below), Row 2, Capacitor 1, has a value of 17.97822949, I would like to find the best row, that together with this capacitor they would have a combined value of 36 (which means, a capacitor that it's value is the closest to 18.02177051).

**Challenge/Problem**: find a combination of Match, Min and Abs that will return the row number, and the capacitor value (Column C and Column D).

[image]

Current code I have:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Match_Min_Abs()

Dim C_Sht                               As Worksheet
Dim C_Col                               As Integer
Dim C_Row                               As Long
Dim Last_Row                            As Long
Dim Capacitor_Val                       As Double
Dim Current_Rng                         As Range
Dim Row_Found                           As Long
Dim Minimum_Gap                         As Double


Set C_Sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("C_Data")

' find last row in sheet
Last_Row = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row

' Capacitors column B
C_Col = 2

For C_Row = 2 To Last_Row - 1

     ' set current search range (from next row till last row)
    Set Current_Rng = C_Sht.Range(Cells(C_Row + 1, C_Col), Cells(Last_Row, C_Col))


    ' ****** this is the part I can't get the right set of functions to work *****
    Row_Found = Application.Match(WorksheetFunction.min(Abs(36 - (Current_Rng + Cells(C_Row, C_Col)))))

   ' Capacitor_Val = Application.Index(Current_Rng, Application.Match(WorksheetFunction.min(Abs(Current_Rng - 36)), Abs(Current_Rng - 36), 0))

    C_Sht.Cells(C_Row, C_Col + 1).Value = Row_Found
    C_Sht.Cells(C_Row, C_Col + 2).Value = Capacitor_Val

Next C_Row

End Sub
```

Comment: the worksheet array formula is `=MATCH(MIN(ABS(36-($B$2:$B$48+B2))),ABS(36-($B$2:$B$48+B2)),0)`  so you can always use WorkSheet.Evaluate Changing `B2` references to your cell value

Comment: `Row_Found = C_Sht.Evaluate("MATCH(MIN(ABS(36-(" & Current_Rng & " + " & C_Sht.Cells(C_Row, C_Col).Address & "))),ABS(36-(" & Current_Rng & " + " & C_Sht.Cells(C_Row, C_Col).Address & ")),0)")`

Comment: @ScottCraner the first formula giving me an `#NA` result. The second one, when implementing in VBA throws a `Run-time error 13 Type Mismatch`. did it work on your test ?

Comment: I did the second in the comments.  I did not test it.  I may have misplaced a `"` or something.  The first I did test on the worksheet itself and it gave the correct answer.  It is why it is in the comments.  I will not have time till tomorrow night my time which is about 24 hours from now to test.  It should return a long.

Comment: @ScottCraner thanks for your help, you can rest in the weekend :) It will be great if you could check it out on Monday

Comment: @ScottCraner thanks a lot :) I got your code to work, need some space removing and add `Current_Rng.Address`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the help of **@Scott Craner**, with some minor modifications (need to add `Current_Rng.Address` , and remove some extra `spaces`) I got this to work.
This is important, since working with 2 `For` loops to cover Excel sheet with over 5000 components, sometimes took longer than 2 minutes to run.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Match_Min_ABS()

Dim C_Sht                               As Worksheet
Dim C_Col                               As Integer
Dim C_Row                               As Long
Dim Last_Row                            As Long
Dim Capacitor_Val                       As Double
Dim Current_Rng                         As Range
Dim Row_Found                           As Long
Dim Minimum_Gap                         As Double
Dim Function_Str                        As String


Set C_Sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("C_Data")

' find last row in sheet
Last_Row = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row

' Capacitors column B
C_Col = 2

For C_Row = 2 To Last_Row - 2

     ' set current search range (from next row till last row)
    Set Current_Rng = C_Sht.Range(Cells(C_Row + 1, C_Col), Cells(Last_Row, C_Col))

    ' use a string first (easier to debug later)  
    Function_Str = "MATCH(MIN(ABS(36-(" & Current_Rng.Address & "+" & C_Sht.Cells(C_Row, C_Col).Address & ")))," & _
            "ABS(36-(" & Current_Rng.Address & "+" & C_Sht.Cells(C_Row, C_Col).Address & ")),0)"                    
    Row_Found = C_Sht.Evaluate(Function_Str) + C_Row     

    Capacitor_Val = C_Sht.Cells(Row_Found, C_Col)
    C_Sht.Cells(C_Row, C_Col + 1).Value = Row_Found
    C_Sht.Cells(C_Row, C_Col + 2).Value = Capacitor_Val

Next C_Row

End Sub
```

Comment: Glad you got it working.  sorry I missed the `Address`.